# Symfony2: transactions fail with "There is no active transaction."

Tags: symfony, pdo, transactions, doctrine, rollback

I've spend several hours trying to resolve this issue. Google and Stackoverflow didn't help much either. So any advice is most welcome here.

I'm trying to apply a rollback logic with transactions when updating two tables in relation:

The code in general is:

```
// ...
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

foreach($dataArr as $data) {
    $userObj = $em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:User')->find($userId);
    $userObj->setActive(1);
    $em->persist($userObj);
    $em->getConnection()->commit();
}

$storeObj = $em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Store')->find($storeId);
$storeObj->setIsOpen(1);
$em->persist($storeObj);
$em->getConnection()->commit();

try {

    $em->flush();
    $em->clear();    

} catch(Exception $e) {

    $em->getConnection()->rollback();
    $em->close();
    throw $e;

}
```

My PDO drivers are enabled, updating without transactions works as expected, but once I beginTransaction() and try to commit() nothing works and I get the **There is no active transaction.** exception.

Some sources suggested using only commit() without persist() but it doesn't make any difference. I'm probably doing something really stupid here, but I just cannot see what it is.

Comment: I believe you need to flush before you commit, because commit is at the DB level, persist doesn't really do anything other than mark the entity for persistence on the next flush, while flush actually execute the queries, and you have to have some kind of query execution before you can commit.

Comment: @prodigitalson You were absolutely right: I removed the `$em->getConnection()->commit()` from the foreach cycle and right after that and just used it before the `$em->flush()`. Works like a charm now. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, either you made an error in your solution or I was wrong. My suggestion was to flush, then commit. Your solved is little different than your initial code in terms of what I thought the problem was. If what you posted works then it must have been the multiple commit statements you had since that is what essentially changed.

Comment: Also you should not amend your question with the answer... You can answer your own question, although there is a waiting period period before you can mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @prodigitalson I moved the solution to its own answer, thanks. But really though, once I removed the commits() that were right after the persist() and only used a single commit() before the flush() it was OK.

Answer (score 12):

After

```
$this->em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
```

you must write:

```
$this->em->getConnection()->setAutoCommit(false);
```

It works for me :)

Answer (score 6):

I once accidentally got this error
by doing following:

```
$em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
try {
    $em->persist($entityA);
    $em->flush();

    $em->persist($entityB);
    $em->flush();

    $em->getConnection()->commit();
    //exception thrown here
    $mailer->send($from, $to, $subject, $text);
} catch (\Exception($ex)) {
    $em->getConnection()->rollback();
}
```

So, you already have guessed that there should not be any code after commit as in the case when this arbitary code($mailer service in our example) throws an exception transaction would be closed before the moment catch block is executed. Maybe this will save a minute or two to somebody:)

Answer (score 5):

Since the version 1.5.2 of [DoctrineBundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/commit/0b56da0e3dfffd005bfb1585914e6d5ad1bc3eda), you can configure the connection to use [`auto_commit`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.8/reference/transactions.html#auto-commit-mode) in the configuration of your project.

```
# app/config/config.yml (sf2-3) or config/doctrine.yaml (sf4)
doctrine:
    dbal:
        auto_commit: false
```

Comment: Unfortunately this stopped my data fixtures to be flushed to database.

Answer (score 3):

As @prodigitalson correctly suggested I needed to do a commit() before the flush() in order for the get the queries executed. So the working code now is:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

foreach($dataArr as $data) {
    $userObj = $em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:User')->find($userId);
    $userObj->setActive(1);
    $em->persist($userObj);
    // this is no longer needed
    // $em->getConnection()->commit();
}

$storeObj = $em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Store')->find($storeId);
$storeObj->setIsOpen(1);
$em->persist($storeObj);
// this is no longer needed
// $em->getConnection()->commit();

try {

    // Do a commit before the FLUSH
    $em->getConnection()->commit();
    $em->flush();
    $em->clear();    

} catch(Exception $e) {

    $em->getConnection()->rollback();
    $em->close();
    throw $e;

}
```